# How to handle downloading popup alert, while downloading a file in chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit

Point 1. If I launched normal chrome driver without loading any profile then it would block all exe (keep/discard)

Point 2. When I provided my chrome profile, these are my observations:

1. Clean exe downloading normally
2. Download error exe giving same dialogue on chrome driver as normally on chrome browser
3. **Issue is here**: those exe which are througing alert of keep/decline popup normally ...those are normally downloading on driver.

SNAPSHOT attached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtZ18.png)

I am loading chrome profile by this pattern

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+userProfile);
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("test-type");              
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

So this is the main Issue

One more thing:  Actually these popups are not html pages. These are over layer on chrome so any technique to spy those using any other free tool? or selenium?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to handle it in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```